# How to Calculate Cosine Similarity Using TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, cosine-similarity

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('shops.csv', sep='|') 
df.columns = ['name',  # 상호명
              'cate_1',  # 중분류명
              'cate_2',  # 소분류명
              'cate_3',  # 표준산업분류명
              'dong',  # 행정동명
              'lon',  # 위도
              'lat'  # 경도
              ]
df['cate_mix'] = df['cate_1'] + df['cate_2'] +  df['cate_3']
df['cate_mix'] = df['cate_mix'].str.replace("/", " ")

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer  # 피체 벡터화
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity  # 코사인 유사도


count_vect_category = CountVectorizer(min_df=0, ngram_range=(1,2))
place_category = count_vect_category.fit_transform(df['cate_mix']) 
place_simi_cate = cosine_similarity(place_category, place_category) 
place_simi_cate_sorted_ind = place_simi_cate.argsort()[:, ::-1]
```

At this time, I want to calculate the cosine similarity as above,
via tensorflow
Is there any way to calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
y_true = [[0., 1.], [1., 1.]]
y_pred = [[1., 0.], [1., 1.]]
cosine_loss = tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)
cosine_loss(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
```

Source: [TensorFlow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CosineSimilarity)